# How to calcuate thevenin voltage with two voltage sources

Tags: voltage, current, thevenin, load

In the following problem, calculating Thevenin's resistance is simple enough , 0.1 ohms. However I cant seem to calculate the Thevenin's voltage when there are two voltage sources? How could I apply KCL or KVL to find the Thevenin's voltage in order to solve the problem?
[image]

Comment: You can solve this circuit directly using KVL (mesh analysis). Or using superposition and the voltage divider rule. Or KCL (modified node analysis).

Comment: Thevenin's voltage is the open circuit voltage (when Rl is not connected). When Rl is replaced with an open circuit, only a single loop is remaining. Apply KVL on that loop to find the current. once the current is known, the open circuit voltage can be found out.

Comment: or use my method which takes less than 1 minute for 25A. or 10 seconds here.. Vavg=10.0V , Req=0.1 , I=10/(0.1+0.3)=25

Comment: Jramb0, Are you familiar with the Norton equivalent? If so, you can convert your two voltage sources with series resistances into two current sources with parallel resistances. This allows you to sum the current sources into just one, combine the two parallel resistances into one, and then convert this new current source and parallel resistance back into a voltage source with a series resistance. Is that something you can handle?

Answer (score -1):

Here’s a useful example from the book “practical electronics for inventors”

[image]